# Input points to certain elements in a list of tuples

Tags: input, python-3.x, tuples

I have a list of tuples as follows:

```
EXCHANGE_DATA = [('AIA', 'Auckair', 1.50),
                 ('AIR', 'Airnz', 5.60),
                 ('AMP', 'Amp',3.22), 
                 ('ANZ', 'Anzbankgrp', 26.25),
                 ('ARG', 'Argosy', 12.22),
                 ('CEN', 'Contact', 11.22),
                 ('CNU', 'Chorus',3.01),
                 ('DIL', 'Diligent', 5.3),
                 ('DNZ', 'Dnz Property', 2.33),
                 ('EBO', 'Ebos', 1.1)]
```

What I want to do is have the user input a series of the codes (the first element in each tuple) in these tuples separated by commas (such as AIA, AIR, AMP) and have the program return the entire tuple the input is referring to. For example if the input was AIA, AIR, AMP the program would return:

```
('AIA', 'Auckair', 1.50)
('AIR', 'Airnz', 5.60)
('AMP', 'Amp',3.22)
```

I am relatively new to programming so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a helper dictionary. This is a good trick to avoid having nested loops.

```
>>> EXCHANGE_DATA = [('AIA', 'Auckair', 1.50),
...                  ('AIR', 'Airnz', 5.60),
...                  ('AMP', 'Amp',3.22), 
...                  ('ANZ', 'Anzbankgrp', 26.25),
...                  ('ARG', 'Argosy', 12.22),
...                  ('CEN', 'Contact', 11.22),
...                  ('CNU', 'Chorus',3.01),
...                  ('DIL', 'Diligent', 5.3),
...                  ('DNZ', 'Dnz Property', 2.33),
...                  ('EBO', 'Ebos', 1.1)]
>>> inp = "AIA,AIR,AMP"     # could come from input()
>>> exchange_dict = {i[0]:i for i in EXCHANGE_DATA}
>>> [exchange_dict[x] for x in inp.split(',')]
[('AIA', 'Auckair', 1.5), ('AIR', 'Airnz', 5.6), ('AMP', 'Amp', 3.22)]
```

If the input can contain extra spaces, you can strip them like this

```
>>> [exchange_dict[x.strip()] for x in inp.split(',')]
[('AIA', 'Auckair', 1.5), ('AIR', 'Airnz', 5.6), ('AMP', 'Amp', 3.22)]
```